# Why is back_populates needed when you can control data?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Learning some Flask/SQLAlchemy and stuck on a notion for the models.

I would like to preface, I browsed a few Stackoverflow threads about this, and read the documentation, but still struggling to wrap my head around the necessity.

While I understand the concept of `back_populates`, or maybe I just think I do, but really don't, because I'm asking this question:

**Why do we need to add `back_populates`? If I've identified the foreign key (see example below) and relationship, why is it necessary to add explicitly back_populates, or even the more confusing for beginners in my opinion, `backrefs`.**

Is this just to establish 1-1, 1-M, M-M, etc... relationships? If so why is that necessary? Couldn't I theoretically control the relationship with the data in the tables. (I.e. by having duplicate foreign keys in one table  (see below) ).

Parent Table:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Child Table:

| ID | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

Coming from a heavy SQL/database world, so if any similar related concepts apply that would be helpful.

ELI5 please.

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```